# Why paste operation pastes nothing?

Tags: excel, vba

Why the code below pastes nothing? It actually copies what I want, but the paste operation doesn´t work.

```
With Workbooks(NomeAmostra)
     Range("B55").Copy
End With

     Workbooks("Recuperar (simplificada)").Sheets("DadosProcessados").Activate
       Range("AG" & n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues 'Colagem dos resultados
         Set Horario = Range("AG" & n)
            Horario = Left(Horario, Len(Horario) - 4)
```

I´ve changed it and now it works just fine, but I don´t understand the reason.

```
Workbooks(NomeAmostra).Activate
Range("B55").Copy

  Workbooks("Recuperar (simplificada)").Sheets("DadosProcessados").Activate
     Range("AG" & n).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues 'Colagem dos resultados
       Set Horario = Range("AG" & n)
         Horario = Left(Horario, Len(Horario) - 4)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing a DOT before the range object

Change

```
With Workbooks(NomeAmostra)
    Range("B55").Copy
End With
```

to

```
With Workbooks(NomeAmostra)
    .Range("B55").Copy
End With
```

Also you might want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: @mehow: Oops sorrry :)